# How to configure websocket?

Tags: javascript, heroku, websocket

On the local server, these settings work

```
CHAT_WS_SERVER_HOST = '0.0.0.0'
CHAT_WS_SERVER_PORT = 3000
CHAT_WS_SERVER_PROTOCOL = 'ws'
```

And the chat is working fine, but on Heroku there is an error(Chrome):

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://0.0.0.0:41540/jgvnf53ky1m1lxt1vrka9lcnfilwhkrv/Pechkin' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

On Heroku I use such settings:

```
CHAT_WS_SERVER_HOST = '0.0.0.0'
CHAT_WS_SERVER_PORT = os.environ['PORT'];
CHAT_WS_SERVER_PROTOCOL = 'ws'
```

Python code
`websocket = new WebSocket(base_ws_server_path + '{{ request.session.session_key }}/' + opponent_username);`

JS code on client
`websocket = new WebSocket(base_ws_server_path + 'jgvnf53ky1m1lxt1vrka9lcnfilwhkrv/' + opponent_username);`

Fihish
`ws://0.0.0.0:41540/jgvnf53ky1m1lxt1vrka9lcnfilwhkrv/Pechkin`

I read that this is a problem because of the certificate (wss \ https), but I don't use him now... or with the wrong IP

Upd_1
[image: error Still in CONNECTING state]

[image: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.]

Answer (score 0):

The IP address `0.0.0.0` refers to the local server. When your browser connects to that address, it will reach the computer where the browser is running (e.g. your laptop). Since you want it to connect to your Heroku app, you need to replace the value `0.0.0.0` with the hostname for your Heroku app, e.g. `your-app-name.herokuapp.com`. This way, the browser will connect over the internet to your Heroku app instead.

The URL in the browser should look like `ws://your-app-name.herokuapp.com:...`

Comment: Hi Matt,

If i do `ws://your-app-name.herokuapp.com:PORT` then I get an error `OSError: [Errno 99] error while attempting to bind on address ('ip', port): cannot assign requested address` 

If i go to the error address, then the page `There's nothing here, yet.`

Comment: It sounds like the server code is using `CHAT_WS_SERVER_HOST` as both the address to listen on, and the address for the browser to connect to. That won't work. The listen address needs to be `0.0.0.0`, while the browser connects to `your-app-name.herokuapp.com`

Comment: If you have any further questions, please show all of your code

Comment: Matt thanks for the help! I did as you said. It seemed to work out, but another error appeared. See update 1. I use https://github.com/Bearle/django-private-chat

Comment: @DevKD Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: @Matt Brown no.

Comment: @DevKD I actually did get it worked out. Take a look at my solution [here](https://github.com/Bearle/django-private-chat/issues/40). My comment should allow you to run it on Heroku. The key is to run the chat server as a separate application.

Comment: @MattBrown Thank! I'll try it in the next projects!